# Updating table value from subform

Tags: ms-access

I am Fairly new with MS Access and run into a problem

I have a data tables called [Serial Numbers] and there I have Fields SN 1, SN 2, SN 3, SN 4 etc.
Those Values are coming from Form called [SN Data]

I have another table Called [Service Redords] Where I have fields New SN, Old SN these values are given from subform called [Service]

On subform New SN is text box and I have a combo box where I select which SN I want to replace With New SN on Serial Numbers table.

So once I enter New SN value to txt box and after updating Combo box I want combo box value e.g 
1 to rewrite value on [Serial Numbers].SN 1

How to do this? I would Appreciate any help. I don't seem to find solution at all.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to post any code relating to this? Please do so if you can. At the moment it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see how your combobox is coming into play. Can you elaborate more on that piece of functionality? So far, I see a query that needs to be ran on an After Update event handler, but I'm not exactly sure what it should do?